# cannot run "npm run build" for a react project on mac m1

Tags: reactjs, macos, npm, apple-m1

we have a react project that builds without problems on an intel mac.
however on a mac m1 the project does not want to build

this is the only respnse from `npm run build`

```
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/.../projects/app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-scripts build
```

node v15.8.0 is installed as well as npm v7.5.0. node_modules is uptodate.

Comment: running `sh -c "react-scripts build"` gives the same: The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.

Comment: also the system has 16GB and in use 6GB, there is enough memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution here is to upgrade/reinstall node from homebrew (this helped me). I ran `brew upgrade node` on terminal, and it seemed to work fine after that.